# Get Hbase processor filter row by timestamp

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to use HBase get processor in NIFI, and i want to do this command in the hbase processor is it possible ?

```
scan 't1', {COLUMNS => 'c1', TIMERANGE => [1303668804, 1303668904]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GetHBase processor is made to do incremental extraction from an HBase table based on the timestamp. The Initial Time Range property determines whether the min time starts at 0 or at the current time, after that the processor is keeping track of the max time seen in the previous execution and using that as the min time in the next execution. So you can't provide your own timerange since the processor is managing that for you.

Answer (score 1):

The GetHBase processor always looks for incremental updates based on the timestamp. Basically it recognizes the new/updated data automatically.

But if you still want to read row specifically for timestamp(s), you have to use regular expression in the following format in the tab "Filter Expression":

TimeStampsFilter(timestamp1,timestamp2....timestampn)

You can find a list of these filters in: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/admin_hbase_filtering.html